# Number of equivalence classes of functions of real variable with the a.e relation.

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, lebesgue-measure

What is the cardinal of the set $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R};X)/ \sim$ where $\sim$ is the relation $f\sim g \iff \mu(\{x\in \mathbb{R};f(x)\ne g(x)\})=0$ and $|X|=|\mathbb{R}|$?
I guess that is $\mathfrak{c}$ but I can't prove it.

Comment: See this [11 January 2007 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=5480960).

Comment: Do functions count as similar if they differ on a _nonmeasurable_ set?

Comment: No, the set need to be measurable and have 0 measure to be equals.

Comment: What is $\mathcal F(\Bbb R,X)$?

Comment: @Dave: The names there, and the email addresses... wow.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: If you go back in time some you can find quite a few well known people in sci.math, such as [Curtis T McMullen](http://mathforum.org/kb/search!execute.jspa?userID=120086&forceEmptySearch=true&rankBy=9&forumID=13&objID=f13) (1998 Fields medal). Even more is available searching google's sci.math archive (Math Forum didn't start until 1996).

Comment: @Dave: I am well aware of that, of course. I was more impressed by Herman Rubin, and the probably-then-grad-student Arturo Magidin.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: I didn't know (then or just before reading your comment) that Arturo was a graduate student then, this not being something (for some reason) I recall ever wondering about. On the other hand, I knew who Herman Rubin was, and he was a very frequent poster on sci.math and many other groups.

Comment: @Dave: I don't know if he was a grad student then. But he was a grad student in Berkeley. Maybe at the time he already finished and just used the email address for usenet related things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is $2^c$....[1].. Let $D$ be the set of uncountable closed subsets of $R$. We have $|R|=c$ and $|d|=c$ for $d\in D$. We can show there exists a family $E$ of pairwise disjoint subsets of $R$ with $|E|=c$, such that $e \cap d \ne \phi$ for all $e \in E ,d \in D$. So if $\phi \ne S \subsetneqq E$ then $\cup S$ is not measurable...[2].. For $ \phi \ne S \subsetneqq E$  , let $f_S :R \to \{0,1 \}$ be the characteristic function of  $\cup S$. Now for distinct  $S,T$ with $\phi \ne S \subsetneqq E$ and $\phi \ne T \subsetneqq E$, we have  $\phi \ne A \subsetneqq E$ where $A= (S-T)\cup (T-S)$, and $\{ x : f_S \ne f_T \} =  \cup A$ which is non-measurable, so $\chi _S$ and $\chi _T$ are inequivalent...[3]..  I will supply the details about the existence of  $E$ if asked. It only depends on |$C|=c$,  and $d \in C \implies |d|=c$. I am very very slow at typing in LaTeX and not very good with it yet. The reason that $\cup S$ is not measurable when $\phi \ne S \subsetneqq E$ is that the inner measure of $\cup S$ and the inner measure of $R- \cup S$ are both $0$ because neither of them has an uncountable closed subset.

Comment: Are you assuming the continuum hypothesis? Otherwise I don't see how you conclude $|d|=\mathfrak c$ for $d\in D$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Any uncountable closed set has size continuum.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: Is that obvious?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Not quite, but it is classical, due to Cantor. In fact, there was this project in the early years of descriptive set theory trying to prove the continuum hypothesis by arguing "inductively" on the complexity of the sets of reals involved, inspired by this theorem. The result is this: 1. Any perfect set has size continuum. Essentially, we can embed $2^{\mathbb N}$ into the set. 2. Any uncountable closed set is the union of a countable set and a perfect set. The proof of this uses the notion of Cantor-Bendixson derivative: Let $C'$ be the set of limit points of a set $C$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Suppose $C$ is closed. Note that $C'\setminus C$ is countable (the points there are isolated). Repeat, so $C''\setminus C'$ is countable, etc. Continue transfinitely, letting $C^{(\lambda)}$ be the intersection of the prior $C^{(\alpha)}$ for limit ordinals $\lambda$. The  point is that the process stabilizes at a countable stage, meaning $C^{(\alpha+1)}\setminus C^{(\alpha)}=\emptyset$ (so $C^{(\alpha)}$ is either empty or perfect). To see this is done in the standard fashion of assigning rationals to the isolated points at each stage, in an injective manner.

Comment: @HenningMakholm A good reference for this is Kechris's book on descriptive set theory, but you can also find details on several questions in this site.

Comment: (@HenningMakholm Oops... Sorry, it should be $C\setminus C'$ and so on, of course, please excuse the typo.)

Answer (score 2):

I believe I have seen this result before: There are $c$ many pairwise disjoint subsets of $[0,1]$ whose Lebesgue outer measures are all $1.$ Assuming this, the cardinality sought in this setting is $2^c.$

---

Added later: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/119646/is-there-a-maximum-to-the-amount-of-disjoint-non-measurable-subsets-of-the-unit